# Native messaging doesn't work as expected on youtube.com

Tags: javascript, c++, stdin, stdio, chrome-native-messaging

The extension just retrieves the URL of the active tab and sends it to the native app. It succeeds in all the other websites including sub-pages of youtube where a video is playing. The same problem happens in both- firefox and chrome.

The following is the code for chrome

```
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow:true,active:true},onGot);

function onGot(tabs){
    tab=tabs[0].url;
    port.postMessage(tab);
    console.log(tab);
    console.log("Response sent!");
}
```

In the native app, I am reading the size first and then the message. The following is the code for reading the size.

```
    int num = 0;
    unsigned char c;
    log("Listening for data Attempt1");
    for (int i = 1;i <= 4;i++)
    {
        log("Waiting for chararcter");
        c = cin.get();
        int s = (i - 1) * 8 - 1;
        if (s < 0) s = 0;
        num = num | (((int)c) << s);
        log("Read Character from extension");
        log(int(c));
    }
    log("Output Size:");
    log(num);
    if (num <0 || num>1999)        *//EDIT*
        return "NULL";
```

This is my logfile when I try to return the URL to my native application when on "https://www.youtube.com/"

```
Listening for data Attempt1
Waiting for chararcter
Read Character from extension
255
Waiting for chararcter
Read Character from extension
255
Waiting for chararcter
Read Character from extension
255
Waiting for chararcter
Read Character from extension
255
Output Size:
2147483647
```

0xFFFFFFFF is end of file. Which means the standard input stream is closed. This happens only with youtube.com.

Comment: I notice that `tab` is a global variable. Could there be a race condition with page redirects, potentially? Bit of a reach maybe

Comment: I actually wait till the entire page loads and then test it out so its probably not the redirects i think! Also, in javascript there is only one thread to handle the event loops. So there is no possiblity for a race condition. Also, I am first copying the url to variable 'tab', and print it in the console-which succeeds. The issue is in sending to the native app. @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Answer (score 0):

From `std::cin`'s type [`std::istream` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get), one can read:

> ```
> int_type get();
> ```
>
> Reads one character and returns it if available. Otherwise, returns `Traits::eof()` and sets failbit and eofbit.

If you want to modify your code as little as possible, check `c` against `Traits::eof()`:

```
c = cin.get();
if (c == decltype(std::cin)::traits_type::eof()) {
    break;
}
```

An improvement would however be to treat the reading from `std::cin` and the data manipulation in two different part of the code (two functions?) and then use `std::transform` for instance to chain them.

Comment: I think the problem is that the EOF condition is not expected

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I must have missed something. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Don't think I can add anything other than pointing you back to the question ;) You seem to be answering "how can I detect EOF", but the OP already detected EOF (albeit in a more manual way) and is asking _why it's happening_ (why their app doesn't receive the website URL) with this particular website.

Comment: I do agree of course that the OP _should_ have code like you've shown, but that's not the crux of the problem they're asking about if I understood correctly

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I fear you are correct. I'm reluctant to delete it though.

Comment: I actually test for value of num. I've edited the code to add the condition. If cin.get() returns eof, i expect num to be far greater. So that case is taken care of!